# Multiple foreign keys in phpmyadmin

Tags: database, phpmyadmin

I am trying to add 2 forign keys in a table but when I make 2nd forien key it gives error like:

> ## 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`foodsuggestion`.`#sql-b54_1b`, CONSTRAINT `#sql-b54_1b_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Res_id`) REFERENCES `restaurant` (`Res_id`))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure there's no rows in the child table that contains Res_id data which is not in the master table i.e restaurant. Besides it will be more understandable if you include structure of your tables in the question.

E.g:

**master table restuarant**

```
res_id|other column|
------|------------|--
  1   |            |
  2   |            |
```

**child table**

```
id|res_id|other column|
--|------|------------|---
1 |  1   |            |
2 |  2   |            |
3 |  3   |            |
```

this will not work and give foreign key constraint fail error.